# Where can I find Docker Images for the different Sitecore Installs?

Tags: configuration, docker

I have seen a lot of good tutorials about how to setup Sitecore to be used in a Docker container. However, this still gives me the problem of configuring the different server roles (i.e. CD, CM, Processing and Aggregation, Reporting) based on my understanding of what should or should not be enabled. I would love to have a place where I could get the "vanilla" Sitecore installs with the proper configs enabled/disabled for each server role.

I know that there is a PowerShell script that I can in theory use to setup an particular server role, but I was wondering what other resources we had that could make this easier.

**Why I would need this?**
Right now I'm looking at upgrading my 8.1 instance to 8.2, and it's looking like it might take as long as 2 months to be sure that I've got all of the configurations done properly.

Comment: I can't help you with Docker. But while we wait for someone who can; take a look at the Sitecore Express Migration Tool. It should make your 8.1 to 8.2 transition a lot easier. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool.aspx. Unless I misunderstood your question, and the real pain point was actually the sheer number of configuration files on an 8.2 and sorting them all out?

Comment: Yes, that is the real pain point is the number of configuration files and getting them setup correctly for the different environments. The link says that this only works for Sitecore 7.2 to 8.2. How does that apply for the 8.1 starting system?

Comment: The Express Migration Tool is only for upgrades from 7.2 to 8.2, it will not work for in between versions. There is nothing official for Sitecore+Docker support but 8.2.1 should support Azure WebApps (and the appropriate package + Azure Resource Manager templates will be provided for each role). This may be an alternative for you: http://sitecore.robhabraken.nl/index.php/2407/an-introduction-to-sitecore-on-azure-web-apps/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE March 2018**

Docker is still not supported, but you can find some base images here: https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images

This repository was created by combining efforts / assets from repos such as sitecoreops and sitecore-nine-docker and sitecore-docker repos.

---

Docker is currently (as of May 2017) not supported, but it is on the roadmap.

On the other hand Sitecore provide role specific templates for Azure App Services with the latest versions (8.2 update 1+), you can find them here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update3.aspx

Comment: That is helpful information. I'm going to download the packages, and see what information is there.

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I am looking for.